# Where exactly do Tickets and Threads get Inserted Into osTicket Database?

Tags: osticket

Can anyone tell me exactly where, in the overall code files of osTicket, the insertion of **new ticket records** and the insertion of **thread records** is performed?

Are there multiple places in osTicket that actually execute the `INSERT INTO` or does it only happen in one spot?

Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 1):

Threads - class.thread.php

- INSERT `ThreadEntry::create($vars)` (line 1112)
- SET BODY `ThreadEntry::create($vars)` (line 1173), `ThreadEntry::setBody($body)` (line 331)

Tickets - class.tickets.php

- `Ticket::create($vars, &$errors, $origin, $autorespond=true, $alertstaff=true)` (line 2941)

Ticket line number might be different, because of my custom changes.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at /include/class.ticket.php.

Search for "static function create" all you need is there i guess.